# PSQL always return role doesn't exist, how fix?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

When i use `psql -U *anyusername* postgres` it returns error:

> role "*username*" does not exist.

But when I login as superuser and create user by:

```
create user *username* with password 'somepassword';
```

it always returns: `CREATE ROLE`.

Maybe I missed something miss, or is it a problem with my OS?

Info about environment:

- Windows 10
- psql version (9.5.18)

UPD:
results of \l and \du commands.
[image: result of \l and \du commands]

Comment: Specify `WITH LOGIN` e.g. `ALTER USER *username* WITH LOGIN` or `create user *username* with login password 'somepassword';`

Comment: @Lucas _If not specified, NOLOGIN is the default, **except** when CREATE ROLE is invoked through its alternative spelling CREATE USER._ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createrole.html

Comment: @Lucas  Yeah, it's create user, and i find, when i try to create user with username i was create before, then psql return me error with  ERROR:  role "ultwolf" already exists. But, if i quit from this menu, and want to login with that user, db doesn`t find that.

Comment: Connect to database as superuser, perform `\l` and `\du` metacommands and post results here ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57004827/edit) your question)

Comment: For the first glance everything should be ok. BTW here is my quick test: https://i.imgur.com/PiE20UL.png

Comment: Usernames are case sensitive.  Are you matching the all lower-case names that show up in the \du list?